# Use structural induction to prove that $v(G) = e(G) + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, trees, binary

$G$ is an element of FBRT (full binary rooted trees), $v(G)$ = total vertices in $G$, and $e(G)$ = total edges in $G$. I know logically that this is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it using structural induction.

Edit: I already figured out a way to prove this part, but I also need to know what goes wrong when you try to prove this for EBRTs (extended binary rooted trees)? I feel like this formula should also apply to EBRTs, but this is what it says on my worksheet, which I don't get why.

Comment: What are FBRT and EBRT? In any case, to prove the first claim for an arbitrary tree you just need to use induction on the leaves. Any tree has at least two leaves, so consider deleting one leaf and its corresponding edge one at a time. You end up reducing your tree to $\cdot -\cdot$, which has one more vertex than it does an edge. If you keep track of how many vertices and edges you deleted along the way you have proven the first result. For the second, I bet you can find an easy counter-example but I don't know what EBRT means.

Comment: @PhysMath A FBRT is basically a binary tree where each node must have a neighbor (excluding the root) and its base case is always 1 vertex (here's an example [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcNVi.jpg)), while a EBRT can have a random assortment of nodes as well as be empty.

Answer (score 1):

For the base case, pick the simplest tree you can imagine (i.e. one vertex, no edges) and verify that the formula works.

Proceeding inductively, we take some tree $T$ and suppose it is true for all smaller trees. If you pick a vertex $v \in T$ and let $T' = T \setminus v$, then we know the claim holds for $T'$ by assumption. Use this to deduce that it holds for $T$ too.